# Show other user's custom reason when rejecting suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

When I come across a suggested edit in the review queue that has already been given a custom rejection reason, it will be common for me to also want to give the exact same custom rejection reason (if I happen to agree with the rejection reason of the previous reviewer).

I suggest that, in the case where a previous reviewer has cast a reject vote with a custom reason, that there be another radio button, after custom, that contains the exact reason they used.

Another similar option would be to have a link/button that automatically populates the rejection reason with the rejection reason of the previous reviewer (if applicable) directly into the custom rejection textbox.

Yes, I can copy paste, but it's not quite as trivial if there is markup in the custom reason (it's not uncommon to see links to the FAQ or other guidelines in the rejection reason).

Comment: I would actually rather see that you enter your own formulation of your reason. Even if you do agree with the prior reviewer. That IMO would make the rejection stand stronger than what essentially is a "yeah, whatever he said". But maybe I'm too academic in this.

Comment: You can already do that, if you visit the page of the suggested edit.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see what the use would be in this feature. Assuming the user will *actually read* the rejection reasons for their suggested edit, what benefit comes from including the same reason **twice**? The user can already see that from the rejection reason the other user typed out. Why does the system need to be modified and made more complicated so that the second reviewer can just use what the first one wrote? Just select the most relevant reject reason and reject it, or type out your own reason so it doesn't look like you're so copy-pasty.

Comment: Why would seeing the exact same reason, but with two different wordings, be more beneficial?  Additionally, if both reviewers have selected the same reason I'd think you could display it to the user just once.

Comment: I'm not saying it would be more beneficial, I'm saying adding this feature to display the same exact thing would **not** benefit anyone.

Comment: I agree it doesn't need to be displayed twice to the user who suggested the edit, but I also think that, generally, both reviewers will be rejecting for the same reason (even if that reason is custom).

Comment: I still don't see the need for this. You're asking them to take time to build a feature that will likely cause confusion with some users, to achieve what goal? How does this benefit anyone but you? It barely benefits you... You could just select the relevant reason that already exists and be done.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like an appealing idea, but my concern is about automatic populate of rejection from previous reviewer. This can help, but will make some reviewers lazy to provide their own opinion for given rejection of suggested edit.